# Unable to add to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I'm attempting to iterate through a list, 'breadthBoard', and add an array to it,'board'. However, each array I add into the array somehow turns into the into a the original array which is then duplicated even though I've tested the array has been changed.

neighbourNodes is a list which contains all the values adjacent to the currentNode on the board.

```
public List breadthBoard(List neighbourNodes, int [] currentNode, int [][] board)
{

    int x = currentNode[0] - 1; 
    int y = currentNode[1] - 1;
    //create lists
    List breadthBoard = new ArrayList();

for (int i=0; i<3;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<3;j++)
            {

                if (neighbourNodes.contains(board[i][j]))
                {
                    // the temp variables allow me to switch the values then switch back later on
                    int temp = board[i][j];
                    int temp2 = board[x][y];
                    //initial switch
                    board[i][j] = temp2;
                    board[x][y] = temp;// at this point I get a successful swap but it isn't getting added to the breadth board
                    breadthBoard.add(board);

                    //test to see if I get the right results which I do
                    System.out.println("what's being added into breadth board (should be swapped)" + Arrays.deepToString(board)); 
                    System.out.println('\n');

                    switching the values back to the original postions
                    board[i][j] = temp;
                    board[x][y] = temp2;
                    System.out.print("back to normal " + Arrays.deepToString(board));// another test passed
                    System.out.println('\n');

                } 

            }
```

Comment: Where are you getting `x` and `y` from and what is neighbourNodes?

Comment: We need to know more about what's going on. Where is breadthBoard declared, what is it's type?

Comment: I'll add the rest of the method

Comment: You are adding the same array a number of times. using `add` does not make a deep copy of the array. This looks like a dupe of [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: I've added where the breadthBoard is declared along with all the method parameters

Comment: @Jorn Vernee is there an alternative to add? I tried using set but that didn't work either

Comment: @McsethAntwi Using `add` is fine, you just need to make a copy of the board first.

Comment: @Jorn Vernee I've tried using clone but it isn't making a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some tests. 
In fact, `clone()` makes a deep copy with an array of primitive types but it doesn't work in the same way with a two dimension array of primitives.
With an array with two dimensions, you should iterate on the first dimension and perform `clone()` on the `int[]`array of the second dimension :

```
   board[i][j] = temp2;
   board[x][y] = temp;

   //Here, I suppose that the second dimension has always the same size. 
   int[][] clonedBoard = new int[board[0].length][board[1].length];

   for (int t = 0; t < board.length; t++) {
     clonedBoard[t] = board[t].clone();
   }
   breadthBoard.add(clonedBoard);
```

Comment: :) No problem. For information, with this way to do, the swap is not required any longer. The idea is to clone first the array, then you modify directly the cloned array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a method that makes a deep copy of `board`. `clone` only makes a shallow copy.

I would advice wrapping the board inside a class, that has a `swap` method that simply return a new board:

```
class Board {
    private final int[][] board;

    public Board(Board other) {
        this.board = new int[other.board.length][];
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            board[i] = Arrays.copyOf(other.board[i], other.board[i].length);
        }
    }

    public Board swap(int i, int j, int x, int y) {
        Board result = new Board(this); // copy this board

        // swap elements    
        result.board[i][j] = board[x][y];
        result.board[x][y] = board[i][j];

        return result;
    }

    ...

}
```

```
// in the loops
breadthBoard.add(board.swap(i, j, x, y));
```